# Observation model for Extended Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm having a problem in finding the Jacobian of an observation model of a camera in a 3D orbital scenario. There is a satellite and a landmark, the positions of which are described respectively with the vectors $\mathbf{x}=[x, y, z]$ and $\mathbf{x}_L=[x_L, y_L, z_L]$ in the reference frame. The state of the system is $\mathbf{X}=[\mathbf{x};\mathbf{x}_L]$.
Please refer to the figure for the notation.
[orbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqyFT.png)

The observation model has 3 entries:

1) the range 
2) the azimuth
3) the elevation with respect to the orbital plane

I'm trying to compute the Jacobian, and I described the elevation angle in two different (but theoretically equivalent) ways.

\begin{equation}
   sin(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}_L^*||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
    \hspace{10mm}
   cos(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L^*-\textbf{x}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
\end{equation}

The term $\textbf{x}_L^*$ is the projection of the landmark on the orbit's plane:
\begin{equation} 
\textbf{x}_L^* =\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}
\end{equation}
where $\textbf{n}$ is the vector normal to the orbit (which is constant). The previous expressions, if we get rid of $\textbf{x}_L^*$ in order to have everything expressed as a function of the state $\textbf{X}=[\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}_L]$, become:

\begin{equation}
   sin(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}_L+(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
    \hspace{10mm}
   cos(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   sin(\beta)= \dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
    \hspace{10mm}
   cos(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \beta_1= sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}\right)
    \hspace{10mm}
   \beta_2= cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}\right)
\end{equation}

The two observation models are then:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}_1(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix}
range \\
azimuth\\
\beta_1
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{10mm}
\mathbf{h}_2(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix}
range \\
azimuth\\
\beta_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}_1(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{bmatrix}
range \\
azimuth\\
sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{5mm}
\mathbf{h}_2(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{bmatrix}
range \\
azimuth\\
cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}||}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Computing symbolically the jacobians using the two (apparently equivalent) expressions for the elevation, I get: 
\begin{equation}
J_1=\begin{bmatrix}
-0.801 &   -0.401 &   -0.445&       0  &       0 &   0.801&   0.401&   0.4450\\
    0.022 &    -0.044&        0  & -1& -1&  -0.022&   0.044&       0\\
    0.018 &  0.009&   \color{red}{0.01}&      0  &       0  & -0.018&  -0.009& 0.04
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
J_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-0.801 &   -0.401 &   -0.445&       0  &       0 &   0.801&   0.401&   0.4450\\
    0.022 &    -0.044&        0  & -1& -1&  -0.022&   0.044&       0\\
    0.018 &  0.009&   -0.04&      0  &       0  & -0.018&  -0.009& 0.04
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The structure of the Jacobian should be such that the first 3 columns are equal and opposite to the last columns. There's a clear discrepancy in third row of the jacobian obtained through the $\beta_1$ model, altough the numerical values of $\mathbf{h}_1(\mathbf{x})$ and $\mathbf{h}_2(\mathbf{x})$ are the same:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}_1(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{bmatrix}
22.4722   \\ 
0.2636  \\
 0.4612
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{10mm}
\mathbf{h}_2(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{bmatrix}
22.4722   \\ 
0.2636  \\
 0.4612
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I've been looking for hours trying to find what's wrong but to me the equations look fine... Somehow the expressions to compute the observation yield the same value, but their partial derivatives are different.

I would appreciate your help!

EDIT: I tried also using the tangent but the error remains. The procedure for the tangent is the following:

\begin{equation}
tan(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}_L^*||}{||\textbf{x}_L^*-\textbf{x}||}
\end{equation}

With:
\begin{equation} 
\textbf{x}_L^* =\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
tan(\beta)= \dfrac{||\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}_L+(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}
= \dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}
\end{equation}
Taking into account the sign of $\textbf{n}$:
\begin{equation}
tan(\beta)= sgn(\textbf{n} \cdot(\textbf{x}_L-\textbf{x}_L^*)) \dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\beta_3= tan^{-1}\left(sgn(\textbf{n} \cdot[(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n}) \textbf{n}]) \dfrac{||(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}||}{||\textbf{x}_L-(\textbf{x}_L \cdot \textbf{n})\textbf{n}-\textbf{x}||}\right)
\end{equation}

Which gives:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h}_3(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{bmatrix}
22.4722   \\ 
0.2636  \\
 0.4612
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
J_3=\begin{bmatrix}
-0.801 &   -0.401 &   -0.445&       0  &       0 &   0.801&   0.401&   0.4450\\
    0.022 &    -0.044&        0  & -1& -1&  -0.022&   0.044&       0\\
    0.018 &  {0.009}&   \color{red}{0}&      0  &       0  & -0.018&  -0.009& 0.04
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: The expression of the third element among the three $h_i$ is different, in fact they have different partial derivatives. So their sensitivity is different, this is what the red number is telling you. You can have $f(x) = h(x)$ at the same point $x^*$, but their derivatives at the same point (in general) might be different.

Comment: By the way, your state vector has six components, whereas your Jacobians have eight columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 4th and 5th column are there cause the state has also two extra variables, that do not however affect the elevation.
I see your point about the sensitivity, however: shouldn't the sensitivy be the same? The dependence from the state variable shouldn't be affected by the formula through which the measurement is obtained. Correct?

Comment: In general the sensitivity is not the same. You can measure the same angle from different combination of states/formulas. It is the job of the designer to choose the "more robust" one according to the requirements, specifications of the system, etc.  In this case the functions $arccos(x)$ and $arcsin(x)$ have very similar derivatives (they differ just in the sign). You can compute the analytical expression of the partial derivative w.r.t. 'z' of such a functions and then check whether your software computed the right numbers.